# Invalid locator using Protractor and Cucumber

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm trying to execude a code using protractor but i am obtaining this issue :

[12:48:45] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
..
(node:34588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid locator
    at Object.check [as checkedLocator] (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js:275:9)
    at Driver.findElements (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1041:18)
    at C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:159:44Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder. [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder. [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at World. (C:\Users\karro\WebstormProjects\ProtractorTest\test\banking.ts:17:36)
(node:34588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:34588) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:34588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid locator
    at Object.check [as checkedLocator] (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js:275:9)
    at Driver.findElements (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1041:18)
    at C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:159:44Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder. [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder. [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\karro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at World. (C:\Users\karro\WebstormProjects\ProtractorTest\test\banking.ts:18:37)
(node:34588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

1 scenario (1 passed)

I have installed the next :

npm install -g protractor
npm install --save-dev protractor cucumber protractor-cucumber-framework chai chai-as-promised
npm install cucumber-html-reporter --save-dev
npm install mocha -g
npm install mocha --save-dev

And this is my code :

Login.feature:
Feature: Example
  Scenario: Login Success
    When I try to login with valid credentials

banking.ts:

```
let {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
let chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
let expect = chai.expect;
var { browser, by, element }= require ('protractor');
var {Given} = require('cucumber');
var {When} = require('cucumber');
var {Then} = require('cucumber');
var {setDefaultTimeout} = require('cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

    When('I try to login with valid credentials', function() {
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
        element(by.name=('first')).sendKeys('1234');
        element(by.name=('second')).sendKeys('2356');
    });
```

conf.js:

```
'use strict';exports.config = {directConnect: true,//Running chrome
    Capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    specs: ['../features/*.feature'],//set framework options
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'), //just maximizing window before testing
    onPrepare: function(){
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

    } ,//Create html report
   "types": ["chai", "cucumber", "node"],
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types"],
    onComplete: () => {
        var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');
        var options = {
            theme: 'bootstrap',
            jsonFile: './results.json',
            //output: './results.html',
            reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
            launchReport: true,
            metadata: {
                "App Version":"0.3.2",
                "Test Environment": "STAGING",
                "Browser": "Chrome  54.0.2840.98",
                "Platform": "Windows 10",
                "Parallel": "Scenarios",
                "Executed": "Remote"
            },
            output: './report/cucumber_report.html',
        };
        reporter.generate(options);
    },//set cucumber options

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['../test/banking.ts'],
        strict: true,
       // format: [],    //don't put 'Pretty' as it is depreciated
        'dry-run': false,
        compiler: [],
        format: 'json:results.json',    //make sure you are not using multi-capabilities
    },
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
};
```

I have added also a screenshot about my project is done.

Could anyone help me? thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: In protractor test, I often use **element(by.css(''))** , such as: `element(by.css('input[ng-model="first"]'))`. you can try it.

Comment: and `element(by.css('input[ng-model="second"]'))` and `element(by.css('input[ng-model="second"]')).clear().sendKeys(string)`